# SN75176 with 3.3V

Tags: serial, rs485, ttl, transceiver

Can I connect the SN75176 RS485 transceiver with a 3.3V microcontroller? The datasheet says that it must be powered with 5V and all inputs / outputs are TTL, but I'm not sure since the minimum high level input of SN75176 can be 2 volts (should work with 3.3V.)

Comment: That is answered in the SN75176's datasheet! Can you clarify where your doubts come from after consulting that?

Comment: There is also a 3.3V version of this chip. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd10-ep.pdf

Answer (score 3):

In general normal 5V TTL can accept logic inputs from 3.3V CMOS outputs as they reach the required 2.4V minimum logic high and the 0.4 logic low.

However, the 3.3V microcontroller may not accept the 5V TTL signal unless its inputs are 5V tolerant, many are not.

If the inputs are not 5V tolerant you will need to use a level shifter on the input to the microcontroller.

This could be as simple as a couple of resistors for low to moderate speed or a slightly more complex design using a single discrete MOSFET or transistor.

This Maxim application note shows a few alternatives.

[Logic Level Translation](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3007.html)

Comment: Thanks sir! I'm using a stm32f103c8t6 which is 5v tolerant in serial port

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro. That's convenient. you should be good to go. The 75176 will need 5V power of course.